# E4 Focus perspective if view is already opened

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, rcp, e4

I'm developing an E4 plugin application which contains 2 perspectives and a couple of views. I've added these views to the `Eclipse Window->Show View -> Other..` menu and they open accordingly. If I open a view that is already opened in another perspective I would like the application to focus on that perspective instead of opening a new view in the current perspective.

Is it achievable? I already unchecked "multiple" property in the part descriptor but it still doesn't work.

Comment: 'Window > Show View' is 3.x compatibility mode not e4.

Answer (score 1):

'Window > Show View' just opens a view in the current perspective using the `IWorkbenchPage.showView` method.

There is no support for switching to a different perspective.

Comment: i'm using a "view" tag along with a custom category for my part descriptor to make them appear in the "Other.." folder list. Can I change the list of views that appear in the menu based on the perspective i'm in ? Maybe I can enforce a view to be opened from a specific perspective only.